# How to use Remote validation with view models

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, remote-validation

I have a asp.NET MVC 5 project with 4 assembly projects. Those are;

1. Common
2. Domain
3. Service
4. Web.UI

I have a model class in domain layer.

```
public class Employee
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*Please insert employee's first name")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name", Prompt = "First Name")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*Please insert employee's last name")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name", Prompt = "Last Name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*Please insert employee's email address")]
    [Display(Name = "E-Mail", Prompt = "E-Mail")]
    [Remote("IsEmailExists", "Employee", ErrorMessage = "This email is already registered: please enter a different email.")]  
    [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([\+\-_\.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)+@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})$",
                ErrorMessage = "*This email is invalid. Please enter a valid email")]
    public string email { get; set; }

}
```

The Controller class for Employee is in a Web.UI project/Layer. In model class for email attribute, I have used remote validation to check whether the email is existing when registering a new employee. Relavent method to check that is in the Employee Controller.

```
public JsonResult IsEmailExists(string UserEmail)
{
    //check if any of the Email matches the UserEmail specified in the Parameter using the ANY extension method.  
    return Json(!db.Employees.Any(x => x.email == UserEmail), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is not working as I expected. I searched a solution for the problem and what I figured out is, I have to use View models, because I'm using assembly projects. But I have no idea about how to do this. If anybody can help, it would be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to use a view model, but you should. What is not working as expected? (also recommend you use `[EmailAddress]` rather than you `RegularExpression]` attribute)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thank u very much Stephen :) what a mistake i did. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Then perhaps you should consider voting and/or accepting the answer

Answer (score 3):

Your `[RemoteAttribute]` is not working because the method you are calling has an incorrect parameter. It needs to be

```
public JsonResult IsEmailExists(string email)
```

The name of the parameter must match the name of the property you apply the attribute to.

Having said that, you still should be using a view model. The `int ID` for example is not appropriate (the user has not been created yet). And attributes such as `[Remote]` and `[Display]` are not applicable to a data model. And assuming you need a password to register, your view model would need an additional property such as `ConfirmPasswrd` with a `[Compare]` attribute which would not be applicable in a data model.

Refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) for more information on why you should be using a view model and its benefits.

Side note: I recommend you use the `[EmailAddress]` attribute in lieu of your `[RegularExpression]` attribute.